# How to do a toolchain configuration for wxwidgets/c++ project?

Tags: c++11, wxwidgets, bison, flex-lexer, msp430

I am looking for a suitable toolchain configuration for my project, because it should work on windows as well on linux (I programm it on linux). It is a tool for msp430 Texas Instruments MCUs.

I programm it in the language c++, so I will need a c++ compiler, flex, bison >= 3.0  and wxwidgets 3.1.0.

I am thinking about https://buildroot.org/ or https://www.vagrantup.com/ or crossNG or something similar.

But I do not have any experience with those tools. Maybe it is also the wrong approach, so please, can somebody tell how to configure a toolchain working on linux as well windows (mingw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, vagrant is a pretty good idea. It's not quite as easy to use on Windows, but it will work using putty to ssh in to the VM. Since you're already programming on Linux you can just go with what you already use.

Once you have your vagrant box running the way you want it (after installs, etc.) you can use vagrant to save it as a vagrant box that you could distribute to users.

Comment: thx for your answer :) Does it make sense for a gui application? I am considering crosstool-ng and setting up a mingw env.

Comment: @Peter Sorry for the delay. You really have two questions here, I think. One is about distributing a toolchain that is cross platform and the other is about the gui app that is built with that toolchain. I can't really answer the second part, but I will say that if you distribute a vagrant box you could just go with something that works on Linux. No need to make it cross platform with Windows, right?

Comment: I programm on Linux, but it should work on Windows out of the box. Presumed the windows user uses mingw/cygwin...